# Entity Framework Database First Lookup table inserting rows

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, lookup-tables

I have to tables FundAllocation & Allocation.

```
FundAllocation
    - FundAllocationId (Primary Key, Identity)
    - AllocationRefId

Allocation
    - AllocationId (Primary Key, Identity)
    - Allocation
```

Corresponding DbSets for the same are :

```
public DbSet<FundAllocation> FundAllocation { get; set; }
public DbSet<Allocation> Allocation { get; set; }
```

Below are the entities :

```
public class FundAllocation
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FundAllocationId { get; set; }
    public int AllocationRefId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AllocationRefId")]
    public virtual Allocation Allocation { get; set; }
}

public class Allocation
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AllocationId { get; set; }
    [Column("Allocation")]
    public string AllocationTitle { get; set; }
}
```

The Allocation table is a lookup table. A FundAllocation can have an Allocation from the lookup table or not have an allocation at all. However, when I add a new FundAllocation to the DbSet (where FundAllocation.AllocationRefIf is equal to an existing AllocationId), it adds a new Allocation to the Allocation table. How can I prevent this new addition of Allocation to the database table ?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely I don't think this is the right approach but the below line of code worked for me:

```
dbContext.Entry<Allocation>(newFundAllocation.Allocation).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```